# Why isn't this list populating with data?

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular and the data is coming back from my api call. The problem is my list is not populating.

first partial:

```
 <div ng-controller="CustomerController" data-ng-init="init()" class="col-md-2">
    <select ng-model="customerKey" ng-options="customer.Key as customer.Value for customer in customers"></select>
</div>
```

second partial:

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerController">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-5" style="outline: 1px solid black; margin-top: 1%">
        <div class="text-center">
            <div class="radio-inline" ng-repeat="customerOption in customerOptions">
                <input type="radio" id="{{customerOption.Value}}" name="customer" ng-change="getCustomers(customerType)" ng-model="customerType" ng-value="customerOption.Key" ng-checked="customerOption.Checked" />{{customerOption.Value}}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var customer = angular.module('customer', []);

customer.controller('CustomerController', [
    "$scope", "customerService",
    function($scope, customerService) {
        $scope.customerOptions = CustomerOptions;

        $scope.getCustomers = function(customerType) {
            $scope.showContent = false;
            customerService.get(customerType).then(function (data) {
                $scope.customers = data;
            });
        };

        $scope.init = function() {
            $scope.getCustomers("1");
        }
    }
]);
```

service:

```
app.service('customerService', [
"$http", function ($http) {
    this.get = function(customerType) {
        var customers;
        if (customerType == "1") {
            getProduction().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else if (customerType == "2") {
            getTest().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        } else {
            getAll().then(function(result) { customers = result.data; });
        }
        return customers;
    };

    var getTest = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetTest",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };

    var getProduction = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetProduction",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };

    var getAll = function () {
        return $http({
            method: "GET",
            url: "api/Customer/GetAll",
        })
         .success(function (data) {
             return data;
         });
    };
    }
]);
```

If you click on any of the radio buttons, they return the appropriate list to the service function; however, I cannot get the select list to populate with that data

Comment: What happens if you call `$scope.getCustomers("1");` directly at the end of your controller file instead of going through ng-init?

Comment: Could you create a fiddle or a plunkr with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the service is returning customers object instead of promise, which the controller method is looking for.

It should work if you return the promise from the service and leave the success/error handling to the controller.

```
app.service('customerService', [
  "$http", function ($http) {
   this.get = function(customerType) {
    var customers;
    if (customerType == "1") {
        return getProduction();
    } else if (customerType == "2") {
       return getTest();
    } else {
       return getAll();
    }
};
```

Controller:

```
  $scope.getCustomers = function(customerType) {
        $scope.showContent = false;
        customerService.get(customerType).then(function (results) {
            $scope.customers = results.data;
        });
    };
```

Answer (score 2):

The `then` handlers in your customerService `get()` method are assigning the results of the HTTP call to a local `customers` variable, but this accomplishes nothing. By the time that happens, `customers` has already been returned to the caller as `undefined`, and you are most likely getting an error when you call `then()` on that value.

You need to return a promise from `get()` and the `then()` handlers inside `get()` need to have `return` statements in them:

```
this.get = function(customerType) {
    if (customerType == "1") {
        return getProduction().then(function(result) { return result.data; });
    } else if (customerType == "2") {
        return getTest().then(function(result) { return result.data; });
    } else {
        return getAll().then(function(result) { return result.data; });
    }
};
```

There is quite a bit of duplication here, and this can be consolidated:

```
this.get = function(customerType) {
    var customerPromise = 
        (customerType === "1") ? getProduction()
        : (customerType === "2") ? getTest() : getAll();

    return customerPromise.then(function (result) { return result.data; });
};
```